# How to run multiple instances of Docker simultaneously on localhost using docker compose? Simple LAMP microsites

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am evaluating Docker as a move away from Vagrant. Our situation is that we manage about 20 LAMP microsites (WordPress) and need the ability to run multiple sites at the same time on our local machines.

I've been looking at Docker Compose but can't figure out how to allow for each of our sites to run at the same time without conflicting ports. Each site is a simple Apache/MySQL/PHP application. Is there a configuration, technique or strategy to allow X number of sites to run at the same concurrently on localhost? Or, since the stack is the same for each site, should I try for a single configuration to manage them all?

We'd only be using this for local development, not yet ready for container deployments to dev/prod or anything like that - just getting tired of the resource and space overhead of vagrant.

Below is where things are at right now. I'd imagine that each `docker-compose.yml` would be nearly identical for each of our sites. How to run many of these at the same time?

```
version: '3'

services:
  wp:
    image: wordpress:latest # https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:80:80 # change ip if required
    volumes:
      - ./config/php.conf.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/conf.ini
      - ./wp-app:/var/www/html # Full wordpress project
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "${DB_NAME}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db

  wpcli:
    image: wordpress:cli
    volumes:
      - ./config/php.conf.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/conf.ini
      - ./wp-app:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
      - wp

  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8080:80
    links:
      - db:db

  db:
    image: mysql:latest # https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ - or mariadb https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 # change ip if required
    command: [
        '--default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password',
        '--character-set-server=utf8mb4',
        '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
    ]
    volumes:
      - ./wp-data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_NAME}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"

volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: Slightly off-topic but since you're still evaluating your options, have you tried [Local](https://localwp.com/)? I used to develop locally with Varying Vagrant Vagrants, switched to docker for a while, and then I found Local. I really like it, but it might not be your cup of tea.

Comment: Local looks great @over-engineer, thank you for sharing that resource. Always glad to learn about new tools. I'll certainly look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker allows you to have a different local port on the host from the port inside the container. (Similar to vagrant port mapping)
You can therefore assign each instance a different port.

So for example you can use port 81 on localhost to map to port 80 inside the container

```
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:81:80
```

This is the easiest solution.

Another solution is to use a reverse proxy (for example nginx, traefik) and expose only that to the host, routing the requests to the correct docker container instance.

Comment: I wasn't aware that I had that amount of flexibility in regards to what ports are available to map. What are the differences between the 3 port syntax `127.0.0.1:81:80` and the 2 port syntax `80:8000`?

Comment: If you specify an IP it will only bind to that network interface.